# Webpack build - class module is not defined

Tags: javascript, class, webpack, build, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to build export a class and bundle it using [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack).

After building the class, I configured the webpack with all possible options to be configured in `outputs` option, but it still gives `[name of module]` not defined or it is not a constructor.

I tried two approaches

### Approach 1

#### My *classA.js* file

```js
export class classA {

  constructor(target, options) {

    }
}
```

#### My *webpack.config.js* file

```js
module.exports = merge(commonConfig, {
  entry: {
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/classA.js')
  },
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].css'
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        parallel: true
      })
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'classA.bundle.js',
    library: 'classA',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  }
});
```

When I run the code without importing the classA.js in the index.js file, I get an error:

> Webpack build ReferenceError -  classA module is not defined

### Approach 2

#### My *classA.js* file

```js
export default class classA {

  constructor(target, options) {

    }
}
```

#### My *webpack.config.js* file

```js
module.exports = merge(commonConfig, {
  entry: {
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/classA.js')
  },
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].css'
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        parallel: true
      })
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'classA.bundle.js',
    library: 'classA',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    libraryExport: 'default'
  }
});
```

This configuration also gives the same error.

After building the classA.js using webpack, it should autodetect the `new classA()` in the script written in HTML file or in any .js file if we have linked the `classA.bundle.js` file.

Comment: it has been resolved by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It required just a correct and updated way to configure the webpack `output` settings

```js
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'classA.bundle.js',
    library: {
      name: 'classA',
      type: 'umd',
      export: 'default',
      umdNamedDefine: true
    },
    globalObject: 'this'
  }
```

This webpack settings for mode production worked for me :)
Thank You